# Understanding statement of Banach-Alaoglu Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

**Banach-Alaoglu Theorem**: If $X$ is a normed space, then the closed unit ball in the continuous dual space $X^*$ is compact with respect to the weak-* topology.

**Question**: Is the closed unit ball here the closed unit ball with respect to the operator norm on $X^*$, i.e., $\{f\in X^*: ||f||\leq 1\}$?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You need a norm to talk about the unit ball. How many norms do you have on $X^{*}$?

Comment: That's why I asked. I wasn't sure if there are other "natural" norms in $X^*$.